# Same jQuery function for multiple form elements. How do I consolidate

Tags: jquery, element

I have this need to show and hide a div if a checkbox is checked for multiple checkboxes.

Each div's id that needs to be shown will be the same as the checkboxes name.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this without writing a function to handle each checkbox?

```
    $('input[name=checkbox_1]').click(function() {
        if ($('input[name=checkbox_1]').is(':checked')) {
            $('#checkbox_1').show('slow');
        }

        else {
            $('#checkbox_1').hide('slow');
        }
     });
     $('input[name=checkbox_2]').click(function() {
                   if ($('input[name=checkbox_2]').is(':checked')) {
            $('#checkbox_2').show('slow');
        }

        else {
            $('#checkbox_2').hide('slow');
        }
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some type of naming convention going on. You can just reach into the current context object, get the name and work your convention. You might want to give your checkbox fields some special css class to make for easy selection:

```
$('input.someCssClass').click(function() {

    var selector = '#' + $(this).attr('name');

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(selector).show('slow');
    else
        $(selector).hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ID from the name, like this:

```
$('input[name^=checkbox_]').click(function() {
  $('#' + this.name)[this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
});
```

This uses the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get the inputs, then uses their [`.name` property](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_name.asp) to get the appropriate element by ID.  If it's checked, runs `.show('slow')`, otherwise `.hide('slow')` on the element with that ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name^=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if(this.checked){
       $('#' + this.name).show('slow');
    } else{
       $('#' + this.name).hide('slow');
    }

}
```

Edit: Using the 'starts with' selector would be better than checking the indexOf, like others said

Comment: There is rarely if ever a need for `$(this).is(':checked')` inside a checkbox handler, `this.checked` is much simpler/faster all around :)

Comment: @afeng - It's `this.checked` :), `$(this).checked` will always be false, it's not a property on a jQuery object, but rather a DOM element property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle()` instead of `if ... else` here to further reduce code:

```
('input[name^=checkbox_]').click(function(){
    $('#' + this.name).toggle('slow')
});
```

Toggle can also run different functions on alternate clicks instead of just hiding/showing elements:

```
('input[name^=checkbox_]').toggle(function(){
    $('#' + this.name).hide('slow')
}, function(){
    $('#' + this.name).show('slow')
    } );
```

Comment: I'll say from experience `.toggle()` (the handler) is not the way to go 99% of the time...what if the checkbox is checked initially? What if it's reversed?  While `.toggle()` (the hide/show shortcut) "shortens" things, it's not the same effect, doing `hide` or `show` explicitly ensures that the state of the element is the same as the state of the checkbox.  If a user for example clicks the checkbox before the DOM is ready, then this hasn't executed and the state is reverse of what it should be. Or, again, what if the checkbox is already checked and your out of sync initially?

Comment: Then it isn't the solution for him ;)